# Getting the browser to show IFrame or use HttpOnly cookie on different page

Tags: c#, iframe, cookies, browser, windows-phone

Hello I'm developing a Windows Phone app for a web based game.
I have however run into a problem that I cant figure out how to solve, and hope some of you bright people in here have an idea.

I use a java script to log into the page no problem, but unfortunately the webpage is very badly designed and show up wrong on Windows Phone. The page will not scale and therefor only show a small part of the hole page and it is only possible to scroll up and down and not side ways.

I have made a quick image here to show better.
[Link to image on ImageShack](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/507/3fgu.jpg/)

(I dont have rep to post Images yet :-(  )

So the actual game is inside an IFrame in the middle of the page but I can only see a small part of it on the phone and can not scroll horizontally.

I tried to download the page using `string html = webBrowser1.SaveToString();` and then used a regex function to extract the webpage from the IFrame. The problem with this is that the page uses a HttpOnly Cookie and this cookie is used by the IFrame also to identify the user. So if I navigate directly to the IFrame Url, it wont recognize the user even though it has the cookie because it is on a different website..

So my question is is there a way to force the web-browser to focus on the IFrame, or some way of stripping out the rest of the page and only show IFrame but still use the same HttpOnly Cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make a  wraps that iframe, then use the hastag trick ("http://game.com#divwrapper") to navigate to that div. This will scroll the page down

Comment: okay thanks,, could you point me in some direction on how to create a wrap?

Comment: hmm ok, now reading your answer again I think that I made a mistake. "I use a java script to log into the page no problem" means you use js to create an iframe to that page, right?

Comment: no no I log into a page, get the cookie, and is then redirected to the new one that contains the IFrame. So the login is on a different page, and the IFrame is created by the webpage..

Comment: there are multible divs on the page the one I want to have in focus looks like `<div class="board">
  <iframe
    src="http://webpage.com"
    width="960"
    height="800"
    scrolling="0"
    frameborder="0"
    name="board_game"
    class=""
    id="zboard_iframe">
  </iframe>
</div>` hope that makes sense

Comment: So are you using the WebView to load page inside your app? And can you make modification to the HTML code that contains the iframe?

Comment: yes I'm using <phone:WebBrowser> to show the page in the app, and no unfortunately I cannot change the HTML of the page.